# ValueError: could not convert string to float: '11,9'

Tags: python, pandas, read.csv

Trying to convert the column "duration(min)" objects into float:

```py
df1['duration(min)'] = df1['duration(min)'].astype(float)
```

Got the error message:

> ValueError: could not convert string to float: '11,9'

[image].

[image]

Comment: replace the comma for a point.

Comment: images don't replace text

Comment: Is this data coming from a file? Typically the commas would be replaced when reading a file. For example: `df = pd.read_csv('file.csv', delimiter=";", decimal=",")`

Answer (score 0):

```
df1['duration(min)'] = df1['duration(min)'].str.replace(',', '.').astype(float)
```

you have first convert ' , ' into ' . ' and then convert into float

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem with comma, try to replace it with '.'

```
df['duration(min)'] = df['duration(min)'].str.replace(',', '.').astype(float)
```